# Civimobile opens then closes

Tags: civimobile

Civimobile has been working fine for a couple months now.  Now when I try to open the app on my mobile phone, it opens fine, flashes a calendar page, and immediately closes.  I have checked to make sure all of the Civimobile apps are enabled under Settings.  This is an urgent issue so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you running?  Have you upgraded recently?

Comment: CiviCRM Version 5.46.2.  CivimobileAPI  5.9.0.  Civimobile 2.0.  I have not upgraded recently.

Comment: For FYI...the issue occurs on all mobile devices, IOS & Android.  To troubleshoot, I deleted the CIVIMOBILE app from my mobile device and re-added it so that I could see where it fails.  When I re-add it, it asks for the URL and then the login as usual.  I put in the URL followed by the user name & password.  It appears to connect to the proper CIVICRM instance as I can see the correct instance label at the top of the calendar page prior to it closing right away.

Comment: Just updated CIVICRM to version 5.46.3.  No difference.

Comment: @Aidan, any insight that you can provide me?

Comment: Sorry, no.  I was just asking some generic troubleshooting questions and hoping some more familiar with it would chime in. Have you checked the FAQ at https://civimobile.org/faq/ ?  Failing that, try their contact form.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem here. Event calendar: click on a session and the app closes. The issue is with the favourites. After deleting all entries from the database the app is doing fine. I noticed that this was the only difference between those sessions that closed and those that didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Version 5.67.0 CiviCRM running on Drupal 10 and Android CiviMobile 6.2.3 (Nov 2, 2023 version) has the same issue.

Comment: Pls do not add a 'me too' as an Answer. If you don't have the permissions to add as a COmment then let me know and I will convert it to one. Also have you raised this issue with the Extension Maintainers?

Comment: Also did you try the above suggestion of deleting Favourites (if i understand what Gemusehandler is suggesting)